# Why does this simple division between 2 floats not work with java?

Tags: java, floating-point, division

```
System.out.println((26.55f/3f));
```

or

```
System.out.println((float)( (float)26.55 / (float)3.0 ));
```

etc.

returns the result 8.849999.  not 8.85 as it should.

Can anyone explain this or should we all avoid using floats?

Comment: Duplicate of LOTS of questions.

Comment: So going by the answers below... Does this mean if Im doing math that represents, say money, or something where I need exactly the correct answer, that I would get by doing math by hand, I should use ints and insert the floating point at the end, or are doubles satisfactory for these situations?

Comment: @user323186: Never use binary floats for money, use a decimal type instead. As for "exactly the correct answer", that's actually not possible in many cases, and floats can be far more exact than ints for many. Do read the site I liked to.

Comment: No, doubles will have the same problem as floats due to how binary floating point number encoding works.  Either use ints and when you need to show it render it as a String with the point in the right place; or use Java's BigDecimal class.

Comment: Yup Michaels link looks like the shortest most concise answer explaing the stiuation well. WD Michael

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/):

> Q: Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2
>   add up to a nice round 0.3, and
>   instead I get a weird result like
>   0.30000000000000004?
>
> A: Because internally, computers use a
>   format (binary floating-point) that
>   cannot accurately represent a number
>   like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.

In-depth explanations at the linked-to site

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Wikipedia's article on Floating Point, specifically the [Accuracy Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) section.

> The fact that floating-point numbers
>   cannot precisely represent all real
>   numbers, and that floating-point
>   operations cannot precisely represent
>   true arithmetic operations, leads to
>   many surprising situations. This is
>   related to the finite precision with
>   which computers generally represent
>   numbers.

The article features a couple examples that should provide more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Explaining is easy: floating point is a binary format and so can only represent exactly values that are an integer multiple of `1.0 / (2 to the Nth power)` for some natural integer `N`.  `26.55` does not have this property, therefore it cannot be represented exactly.

If you need exact representation (e.g. your code is about accounting and money, where every fraction of a cent matters), then you must indeed avoid floats in favor of other types that do guarantee exact representation of the values you need (depending on your application, for example, just doing all accounting in terms of integer numbers of cents might suffice).  Floats (when used appropriately and advisedly!-) are perfectly fine for engineering and scientific computations, where the input values are never "infinitely precise" in any case and therefore the computationally cumbersome burden of exact representation is absolutely not worth carrying.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we should all avoid using floats wherever realistic, but that's a story for another day.

The issue is that floating point numbers cannot exactly represent most numbers we think of as trivial in presentation. 8.850000 probably cannot be represented exactly by a float; and possibly not by a double either. This is because they aren't *actually* decimal numbers; but a binary representation.

Comment: -1 for the first sentence. There is absolutely no reason to avoid floats for most applications. They're *more* accurate than many alternatives - they just don't conform to some expectations we have based on a decimal system. Most of the time, that is not really a problem.

Comment: @Michael: Floats will lead you down many winding paths; but the core of the issue is: They are slower than integral numbers, and they don't allow direct comparison (`==`). There are a lot of applications where they make sense, but often times; integral maths make as much sense (consider, if you will, engineering tasks where sizes are given as integral microns or mm).

Comment: @Williham: engineering tasks are a good example for something where integral numbers are *worthless*, because engineers don't work only with sizes and everything at right angles, but also with forces, volumes, masses, voltages, and a host of other things at varying magnitudes. Doing that all in integers would be insane.

Comment: @Michael: It would certainly not be realistic, no. Insane? Maybe. But I'm not saying to avoid floats in all cases: I'm saying to avoid floats unless you need them.

Comment: @Williham: and I'm saying that you should use floats unless your have specific reasons to avoid them. Pretty much the only good reason to avoid them is doing money calculations.